# Unhandled error in WCF about serviceHostingEnvironment

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I'm a newbie trying WCF. I'm trying to access WCF using android, I had trouble and according to my research json is required to access WCF, so I tried changing it to json.

I changed the Interface to an object type and start having an error shown below

```
The exception message is: The type 'AddItemService.Login', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found..]
```

my Interface method:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Login", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [Description("Returns the Login User ID")]
        int GetUserId(Login login);
```

my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="AddItemService.Login"
                behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="AddItemService.ILogin"
                   behaviorConfiguration="MyEndpointBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RESTBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I don't know why it won't work. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The parameter type of the one parameter to your GetUserId operation is "Login" but the service type is also "Login" are they two different types in different namespaces?  If not, that may be your problem - the service name is the implementation of the service, in your case whatever implements AddItemService.ILogin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the service type specified in the .svc file for the WCF service (the actual markup file, not the code-behind one) is referencing a service class type which doesn't exist.

If you right-click the .svc file in the Visual Studio and choose 'View markup', the 'Service' attribute of the ServiceHost directive in that file needs to contain the name of the class which implements your WCF service interface. Sounds like at the moment it's referencing `AddItemService.Login`, which doesn't exist.